# Problem with Any Chart's Multiple Point Selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, anychart

I am using [anychart](https://anychart.com) for the development of an interactive seat map. Everything is working great so far except one thing. I can't select multiple seats (points) without holding ctrl button from my keyboard.

I googled a lot, reviewed the docs but I can't find any option in anychart's library which will allow the user to select multiple seats without holding ctrl key from their keyboard. It is not even in a single anychart's demos.

Thanks in Advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using the multiSelectOnClick method:

https://playground.anychart.com/api/core/utils/_samples/anychart.core.utils.Interactivity.multiSelectOnClick

Like this:

```
chart.interactivity().multiSelectOnClick(true);
```

Here is a sample for seat map: https://playground.anychart.com/NQkAvZ1z

Comment: You are right, we will update the documentation to reflect this.

Comment: The function multiSelectOnclick(true) seems to be buggy on mobile. Please try opening the playground fiddle you have linked above on mobile

Comment: The event models of desktop and mobile differ. And that means their interactivity also differs. To select multiple points you'll have to click one point, then at the same time click the one you've just selected and the one you'd like to select next. Please check this video: https://vimeo.com/323622445

Comment: I have been struggling...
You are correct about the mobile touch events. When I tap and hold, I can select multiple seats. Isn't there a way to make it select the seat only on tap rather than tap and hold?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not possible in the current implementation.